# "Bundle command not found" in Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, groovy

I have a Groovy script that runs a job in a Jenkins pipeline but it fails when it tries to run `bundle`. I get the error

```
bundle: command not found
```

I thought I was including the PATH variable in my build process but it seems that is not the case

```
node {
  stage 'Bundle Build'
  withEnv(['PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/:sbin/usr/local/bin:$PATH']) {
    sh '''bundle'''
  }
}
```

When I run `which bundle` I get `/Users/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby/bin/bundle`, but my builds run under `/Users/Jenkins/.jenkins`.

How can I use bundle when building a job?

### Update

If I run this however it works

```
node {
  stage 'Bundle Build'
  withEnv(['PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/:sbin/usr/local/bin:$PATH']) {
    sh '''#!/bin bash -l
          bundle'''
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem right.

Comment: Is there a reason for not going the easy route of either supplying the full path to `bundle` or adding the `/Users/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby/bin` to the `withEnv` array?

Comment: have tried that but it still doesnt work, the only way i can get it to work is if i run my shell script as `#!/bin/bash -l` which feels wrong to me

Comment: What shell script?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I've updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
node {
  stage 'Bundle Build'
  withEnv([
      "PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH",
      "RBENV_SHELL=sh"
      ]) {
    sh '''bundle'''
 }
```

Please make sure that the path to `.rbenv` is correct

Comment: Does it possible to also choose ruby version here?